# Imposible eliminar fichero en Linux (CentOS)

Tags: linux, bash, centos

Estoy tratando de eliminar un fichero, pero no lo consigo.

```
[root@HBL01 home]# ls -ltira index.php 
393591 -r--r--r-- 1 apache apache 14335 Nov 23  2021 index.php

[root@HBL01 home]# rm -rf index.php
```

El fichero sigue existiendo:

```
[root@HBL01 home]# ls -ltira index.php 
393591 -r--r--r-- 1 apache apache 14335 Nov 24  2021 index.php

[root@HBL01 home]# lsattr index.php
--------------e----- index.php
```

Si intento escribir en el fichero via *vim*, al final del fichero aparece:

`"index.php" [readonly] 17L, 14335C`

Si cambio los permisos, tampoco se observa ninguna modificación:

```
[root@HBL01 ]# chmod 777 index.php 

[root@HBL01 ]# ls -ltra index.php 
-r--r--r-- 1 apache apache 8230 Nov 23  2021 index.php
```

Qué sucede con este fichero? Como puedo eliminar o poder escribir sobre el mismo?

Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Algunos ficheros pueden tener un atributo que impide que sea borrado incluso por el usuario root.

Puedes listar los atributos extendidos del fichero en cuestión con el comando `lsattr`:

```
lsattr index.php
```

La salida debiera ser un conjunto de guiones:

```
alfonso@pardomino:~$ lsattr Documentos/fondo.same.jpg
--------------e---- Documentos/fondo.same.jpg
```

O, en mi caso, elegido un fichero al azar, muestra activo el atributo "e", que especifica que el fichero está utilizando *extents* para mapear los bloques en disco.

No es cuestión de abordar todos los atributos extendidos en esta respuesta, y además una breve búsqueda en la red puede aclarar mucho al interesado.

En concreto, el atributo extendido que define la inmutabilidad del fichero (no puede ser borrado ni modificado por ningún usuario) es el atributo "i".

Comprueba los atributos extendidos del fichero en cuestión, y seguramente lo tenga activo.

Para modificar los atributos extendidos se utiliza el comando `chattr +-=[aAcCdDeijsStTu]` (+ para añadir) o `chattr -<atributo> <fichero>` para eliminarlos, y el signo "=" para definir los únicos atributos que tendrá un fichero:

```bash
chattr -i index.php
rm index.php
```

Esos dos comandos debieran solucionarte el problema.

ACLARACIONES:

1. Nótese que he reiterado el concepto atributos EXTENDIDOS (diferenciados de los atributos que definen propietarios y permisos, listados con `ls -l` y modificables mediante el comando `chmod`).
2. Ambos comandos `lsattr` y `chattr` solo pueden ser usados por el usuario propietario del fichero o por root.

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

El fichero solo tiene el permiso de lectura para borrarlo o modificarlo, tienes que cambiar, añadir el permiso de modificación como mínimo para tu usuario (nota en este caso tienes que ser el usuario apache o el root de la máquina para cambiarlo o usar sudo si lo tienes). Código de ejemplo para que lo puedas borrar:

```
chmod 766 index.php # ojo, que da permisos a todos para cambiar el fichero
rm  index.php
```

Explicación de los números:
cada digito representa un permiso a un determinado usuario de derecha a izquierda:

El dueño de la carpeta->El grupo que pertenece la carpeta-> otros usuarios.

Chuleta del significado de los dígitos:

0-> sin permiso de nada

1->solo permiso de ejecución

2->solo permiso de escritura

3->escritura y ejecución

4-> solo permiso de lectura

5->lectura y ejecución

6-> lectura y escritura

7-> todos los permisos

**Esto sobrescribe los permisos anteriores para otro método de que lo modifique sin usar numeros, mira el siguiente [link de referencia](https://blog.desdelinux.net/permisos-basicos-en-gnulinux-con-chmod/)** personalmente recomiendo usar los números porque una ya te lo sabes es mucho más ágil.

Comment: si... lo hice, pero sigue sin borrar. De hecho, no se modifican los permisos.

Comment: ¿Eso es raro te ha sacado algún mensaje al intentar modificarlos?

Comment: ninguno. Este es el problema que tengo. Ni deja modificar permisos ni deja eliminar